# Package 'wicd' has no installation candidate

Tags: kali-linux

I want to install `wicd` in Kali but I'm getting this error:

`E: Package 'wicd' has no installation candidate`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

`wicd` has been [removed from Kali](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/wicd), because [it depends on Python 2](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1171012/removed-174tb2-6-from-unstable/). The Python 3 version should be made available in Kali at some point, but until then you’ll have to make do with some other tool.

Answer (score 1):

@Stephen Kitt is correct but it is not just Kali,  many debian derivatives (all with gnome) and Arch linux are all effected.

This is becoming a bigger and bigger issue  as more users upgrade and wicd dependencies are removed

> i.e: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308226/unable-to-install-wicd-network-manager

**History:**

For many years WICD has been the FIX for debian network manager (as OP points out, it is well documented that removing default manager fixes many many general user networking problems in debian derivatives. )

**Problem**

WICD uses Python 2. For better or worse Python3 is being phased into debian architecture and python2 phased out.  This is rendering useless many packages users have reliably depended on as alternatives to some default packages.  WICD is one notable loss to the community.

**Future**

according to WICD dev:
WICD development on hold.......while Python, GTK continue to develop - The WICD project will need several major changes to its code base and will take some time.

> So it appears many debian and debian derivative users will have to find/develop/share new solutions to replace critical default packages that do not work well for users.

@Stephen Kitt : Please share - what other tools??

Comment: I know LXDE@Debian uses `connman`.